# Mongoengine Query using only() on list of reference fields

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have two Documents

```
class Book(Document):
    title = StringField()
    publication = StringField()
    no_of_pages = IntField()
    desc = StringField()
    reviews = ListField(ReferenceField(Review))
    ...

class Author(Document):
    name = StringField()
    books = ListField(ReferenceField(Book))
    desc = StringField()
    ...
```

I want to write a query which given an author's name finds all his book's tiles.

As you can see both the documents have loads of columns, I don't want to get 
all the columns. hence my required fields are

```
`req_fields = ['name', 'books']`
```

and I query this as follows

```
author = Author.objects.filter(name='xyz').only(*req_fields)
```

If I print `author` object, I get:

```
{
_id=ObjectId('50fcf9682c345a0427000019'),
_cls='Author',
name='xyz',
books=[DBRef('Book', ObjectId('50fcd9682c441e0427000019')), 
DBRef('Book', ObjectId('50fcd9682c361e0427000020'))]
}
```

I would like the query to return a list of string for title rather than a list of book objects. How can I modify this? so that the result objects is like the following

```
{
_id=ObjectId('50fcf9682c345a0427000019'),
_cls='Author',
name='xyz',
books=['Title One', 'Title Two']
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you need the books dereferenced call `select_related`  eg:

```
author = Author.objects.filter(name='xyz').only(*req_fields).select_related()
```

Comment: I did not know about `select_related()` but this it not what I want.. I would like the query to return a list of string title rather than a list of objects

Comment: You still need to dereference and that means doing another query.  Currently, you can't return a single field instead, please add a ticket to http://github.com/mongoengine/mongoengine asking for this feature.

Comment: after using select_related(), _data property dereferences correctly and give objects of Book document, but to_mongo() gives DBRef objects still. Is this a Bug?

Comment: No its stored as a DBRef in the database

Comment: what is the final solution for this ?